# Trouble getting XML data to show on HTML using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, xmlhttprequest

I'm working on my new PC builds website and I have trouble getting XML tag with specific attribute to show up in my HTML `<p>` element. My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="2016.6" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parts>
  ...
  <HDDs>
    <hdd id="1">
      <name>DiskOne</name>
      <price>50</price>
    </hdd>
    <hdd id="2">
      <name>DiskTwo</name>
      <price>40</price>
    </hdd>
  </HDDs>
  ...
</parts>
```

I want to find tag `<hdd>` with attribute `id="2"` in above XML and show its child's `name` content in HTML `<p>` element, which has the `id="test-xml"`. I used this jQuery code to get data from XML and show that in `<p>`:

```
  function loadHDDs(name)
  {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'data/parts.xml',
      dataType: "xml",
      success: parseHDDsXml
    });
  }
  function parseHDDsXml(xml, name)
  {
    $(xml).find('hdd[id="2"]').each(function(){
      var name;

      name = $(this).children('name').text();

      $("#test-xml").text(name);
    });
  }
```

I found the code in another website and I don't really know, what do I need to write in brackets after `loadHDDs`, so I wrote `name`. I don't know how to cleanly make the script execute when the page is loaded, so I added `onload="loadHDDs();"` to the `<body>` element on my page. I use Google Chrome debugger to find errors. When I tested my page locally, on my computer, debugger, of course showed that `XMLHttpRequest cannot load`. I uploaded my project to the server and I receive no errors in the Chrome debugger at all, but the text in `<p>` element doesn't change to the XML text. What am I doing wrong? Maybe something is wrong with my script? Or XML document? Maybe I just don't know to execute jQuery script and `onload` just doesn't work? Please, help me! I'm a beginner in jQuery and Javascript, so I kindly ask you to show me the easiest and most understandable way of fixing the problem.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I don't have enough reputation to comment. I added `error` function to my Ajax as Nayeri suggested and now I get an error that `loadHDDs` is not defined. I don't understand that. We can clearly see `function loadHDDs(name)` in my script. I have checked the spelling a hundred times.

Answer (score 0):

Add error function to your ajax to see your errors :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'data/parts.xml',
  dataType: "xml",
  success: parseHDDsXml,
  error : function (a,b,c){
    console.log(a, b, c)
  }
});
```

then your xml file seems is wrong so Remove the `<?xml version="2016.6" encoding="UTF-8"?>` line of your xml file

Comment: @Gustas if u have an external js file  , your html page can't find your js file so check your <script src=""> tag.may be it will solve your problem